# Exclude technologies/keywords on Stack Overflow Talent searches

Tags: support, search, stack-overflow-talent

Is it possible to exclude specific technologies or keywords when searching on Stack Overflow Talent?

As a simple example, is it possible to search for candidates with *Ruby*, but not *Ruby on Rails*?

I have tried adding a `!` before a search, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Nice! That appears to work in the Keywords field. So I can search for `ruby` in the Technologies field, then negate other terms in the Keywords field. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main site you can negate tags by adding a `-` in front of the tag, like so:

> [`[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+-ruby-on-rails)

Your own experiment now showed that you can use one tag in the *Technologies* field and then negate other terms in the *Keywords* field with the solution I offered.